# Ember.js {{#each}} table searching, partial viewing and sorting

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Thanks in advance for the help. I am pretty new to ember.js, but have setup a basic site that has a few pages with tables that loop through my data. These tables are going to be over 100 rows and have images in each row, so I would like some sort pagination or a partial view so as they scroll it loads (preferred solution). I also want the ability to search the table.

I have used datatables.js before, and that would solve most of my problems, but I am not sure if that would be the best solution with ember because it is not able to just grab the table like it normally does.

I am kind of looking for a direction and what other people may think is the best solution. Any links, or plugins, or example code or whatever would be very helpful. Here are some snippets of my code, just a super basic site:

Index Table

```
<table class="prdtTable table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Demo</th>
      <th class="tdLeft">Price</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th># of Columns</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each}}
      <tr>
          <td class="noWrap">{{#link-to 'theme' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td>{{#link-to 'theme' this}}<img {{bind-attr src="image"}} \>{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter">{{price}}</a></td>
          <td>{{description}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter">{{columns}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Free Page Table

```
<table class="prdtTable table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Demo</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th># of Columns</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each}}
      {{#if free}}
        <tr>
          <td class="noWrap">{{#link-to 'theme' title}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td>{{#link-to 'theme' this}}<img {{bind-attr src="image"}} \>{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td>{{description}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter">{{columns}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Index Route

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return App.PRODUCTS;
   }
});
```

Product Route

```
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
       return App.PRODUCTS.findBy('title', params.title); 
    }
});
```

Product Array

```
App.PRODUCTS = [
{
 title: 'Title 1',
 price: '$0',
 free: true,
 description: 'long description',
 columns: 1,
 image: 'images/image.jpg'
},
{
 title: 'Title 2',
 price: '$0',
 free: true,
 description: 'Description 2',
 columns: 3,
 image: 'images/image.jpg'
}, 
...
```

Thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it!

David B